# Added cache-control header to static war file in JBoss

Tags: jboss

I have a bunch of static files packaged into `$JBOSS$/server/default/deploy/foo.war` and accessed via http://example.com/foo/file.html There is no other configuration for `foo.war`.

Is it possible to control the headers of `file.html` to add a `cache-control: no-cache` header without spinning up a servlet?